# How to deal with Claims that could have multiple values?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, jwt, claims-based-identity, claims

So I might be misunderstanding the architecture of claims here, but if I wanted to add a list of specific departments (department id) a user can edit I could create a claim:

`new Claim("CanEditDepartment", "1")`

But expanding on that, what if the user could edit 50/100 departments, do I need 50 claims for this?

- `new Claim("CanEditDepartment", "1")`
- `new Claim("CanEditDepartment", "2")`
- `new Claim("CanEditDepartment", "4")`
- `new Claim("CanEditDepartment", "23")`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're using claims incorrectly.

Your claims should represent who/what the person is. Your app should then look at those claims and map them to *permissions* which are what the user can do with those claims.

Passing around a massive amount of claims slows everything down and/or is unfeasible. What happens when you add more departments? What happens when your app has many more permissions? You have JWT tagged in your question. Do you really want to pass a such a large token in each request?